# if statement regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, if-statement

I would like to scan txt file and look for if statement (an **if** not a SOMETHINGifSOMETHING).

I was thinking about something like that

```
 [\\W|\\s]*if[\\s*|\\(]
```

but it does not work.

How can I make this "if" regex?

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // if (x > 10) a = b;
    int pif = 2;  // if
    int ifa = 3;
    int ifff;
    int kif;
    int cif;
    /*
     if
    */       
    
    int a = 0, b = 0, c;
    
    if (a > b) c = 1;  // wariant jest subwariantem
    if(a > b) c = 1;if (a<b) c=1; if(a==b) c= 7;
    if (a>b) c =1; else if (a==b) c=2;
    if (a>b) c =1; else {if(a==b) c=2;}
    if
    (a<b) c = 7;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think, what this -> `[\\.|\\s]` means?

Comment: *It does not work* is meaningless. What's your code, what did you expect it to do, and what does it actually do?

Comment: FYI, `\\s{0,1}` is same as `\\s?`

Comment: If you want this to be accurate, then a single regex isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: @NPE: It depends on what you mean by "accurate". If the requirements are that all `if` statements are found, then it can be done with a single regex. If the requirements are that all `if` statements are found *but nothing else is found*, then you are correct, it cannot be done with single regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[;\s]+if[\s*|\(]
```

it will not know which are commented out, but it will find all the "if"s and not capture all the somethingIfSomethings.

Comment: This will also match a `System.out.println(" if (when) the sky falls ");` To get it really right regexp is the wrong tool.